# Editing dropdown list dynamically with Javascript - not working

Tags: javascript, html

Ok, I know how to do this - in theory. I have a dropdown list in a web page that I want to edit dynamically with javascript. My dropdown list has been created, empty, with the following HTML:

```
<select id="my_dropdown">
</select>
```

and then this javascript code (run in the head section) is supposed to fill it in with a single option:

```
my_drop = document.getElementById("my_dropdown");
my_drop.options[0] = new Option("Name", "value");
```

I think I'm doing everything by the books but, even stripped to the bone at this point, this code still doesn't work, either on Chromium or Firefox. I have no idea what to try next. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing it in the head, ouside of any `onload` handler, then the DOM is not ready yet.

Either move your javascript to after the element in the HTML, or enclose it in an `onload` function.

eg/

```
<body onload="doMyStuff()">
```

and in the head

```
function doMyStuff(){
    // code here to add item to dropdown
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works. Funny thing, I was just testing, but in the final version the editing function will be bound to another event which will necessarily take place after the body is loaded (since it depends on user input). In other words, the problem wouldn't even have existed had I tried that immediately...

Answer (score 0):

nothing is wrong with your code... i think your DOM isn't ready so try this...

on your HTML  tag

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
```

and add this to your script

```
function myFunction(){
   my_drop = document.getElementById("my_dropdown");
   my_drop.options[0] = new Option("Name", "value");
}
```